# Value returning 0 or NaN instead of actual result

Tags: javascript

Just trying to make a simple weight converter program, but the result keeps giving me NaN or 0. I have coded a similar calculator using basically the same function and it works fine, I'm not sure what I am missing here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="weight.js"></script>
    <title>Weight Converter</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <input id="pounds" type="text" placeholder="Enter weight in pounds"/>
        <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="calc()"/>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var k = document.getElementById('pounds').value;


function calc(){
    var result = (k / 2.2);
    alert(result + " kilograms");
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to get the `.value` *before* the `onclick` has been triggered. On page load, the `value` of the element is an empty string. Try getting the value *after* the click, not before:

```js
function calc() {
  var k = document.getElementById('pounds').value;
  var result = (k / 2.2);
  alert(result + " kilograms");
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="pounds" type="text" placeholder="Enter weight in pounds" />
  <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="calc()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this. Wait for window to load then run calc function (which will already have the DOM available (e.g. any div ID's or classes) since Window.load has been invoked)

```
window.onload = function() {
  calc();
};

function calc() {
  let k = document.getElementById('pounds');
  k.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let result = document.getElementById('pounds').value / 2.2;
    alert(result.toFixed(1) + " kilograms");
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```